# Executing periodically tasks in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I created an app that sends reminder message to clients. But I would
 like to make it send these messages in a specific time .
     I have on my database the deadline and the type of messages already riten. There are 4 types of reminder messages for every
 client:

1. Before 45 days from the deadline
2. Before 30 days.
3. Before two weeks.
4. Before 1 day.

[image]

This is the error that I have now:

[image]

Comment: I would, once a day check whether the messages meet any of these criteria.

Comment: The scheduledexecutorServerice is for executing a task say every 5 seconds or 50 milli-seconds. If you only need to check once a day, you could use Quartz as this will allow you to control the time this happens.

Comment: @PeterRader, No I don't

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks. Do you have a good tutorial on how to do that with Quartz?

Comment: Is it easier if I use Spring?

Comment: The problem is that it is very likely that your jvm will get rebooted in 30 days, So I highly doubt that you could do this without a  persistence  logic.

Comment: @armnotstrong Hmm, thank you for this info.

Comment: @Benz .. just looked at your updated question. Why you have public static void main() method in your web application, this is not the way web application works. I suggest you to first learn how to create simple web application using servlets and then implement/enhance to use quartz scheduler

Answer (score 3):

You can use Quartz Scheduler for this, you need to create Job as below

> **Approach 1: How to use Quartz Scheduler in Standalone java program**

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{
        //your code goes here for sending reminders
    }
}
```

And use the SimpleTrigger to run the job once on the specified time [in `new Date()` in below code](which you need to calculate based on expiration like 45/30/14/1 day(s) before)

Import statements:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
```

---

```
try{

SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail jd = newJob(HelloJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

SimpleTrigger st = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", sched.DEFAULT_GROUP)
    .startAt(new Date())
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
            .withRepeatCount(1))
    .build();

Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(jd, st);

System.out.println(jd.getKey() +
     " will run at: " + ft +  
     " and repeat: " + st.getRepeatCount() + 
     " times, every " + st.getRepeatInterval() / 1000 + " seconds");

sched.start();

}catch (SchedulerException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());;
}
```

> **Approach 2: How to use Quartz Scheduler in Servlets:**

You'll want to add something like this to your WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
     <display-name>Quartz Initializer Servlet</display-name>
     <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
 </servlet>
```

you need a `src/main/resources/quartz.properties` config file for Scheduler

```
# Main Quartz configuration
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
```

you may retrieve the scheduler and use it in your own Servlet like this:

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public init(ServletConfig cfg) {        
        ServletContext servletContext = cfg.getServletContext();
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) servletContext.getAttribute(QuartzFactoryServlet.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
        Scheduler quartzScheduler = factory.getScheduler("MyQuartzScheduler");
        // and continue to implement as in approach 1
    }
}
```

> **Approach 3: How to use Quartz Scheduler in Spring:**

You need to create `quartz-context.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gs.spring" />

<!-- if you need to invoke a method on an object -->
<bean id="simpleJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myBean" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="sendReminder" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
    <property name="repeatCount" value="0"/>
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!-- Scheduler factory bean to glue together jobDetails and triggers to Configure Quartz Scheduler -->
    <bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleJobDetail" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

POJO task bean

```
package com.gs.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("myBean")
public class MyBean {

    public void sendReminder() {
        //send an reminder
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and if I'll need any help I'll let you know.

Comment: I was wondering if there is another solution? I didn't use Spring from the beginning. :/

Comment: @Benz .. then you can use the standalone section, it easy to implement

Comment: I have an error in: JobExecutionContext and JobExecutionException.
I get some suggestions to change: 
**JobExecutionContext** to JobContext or JobExecution
and **JobExecutionException** to JobExecutionAlreadyCompleteException, JobStartException, JobExecutionIsRunningException ...

Comment: @Benz .. you can update the question with what you have tried and the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I updated the question, this is what I've done till now.

Comment: @Benz ... I can see that you are logging the exception. Can you include complete stracktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Benz .. I have update the answer as per latest changes to Quartz API. Please check for the imports also.

Comment: For the Import statements and try&catch block, can I use that in a servlet?

Comment: @Benz .. quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler is the way to use quartz with servlets

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I used the code that you provided in your update answer.

Comment: @Benz .. there are ways to implement quartz in various types of application. The one you tried is easy for standalone application although this will also work in servlets but idea is to have single scheduler initialized using the web.xml. I have updated the answer (approach 2) to use the quartz within servlets

Answer (score 2):

You can use Quartz to schedule a task to verify conditions every day/hour.

[Quartz tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) provides extensive examples for number of use cases.

Quartz also integrates nicely with [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz). Your recurring task implementation:

```
public class RecurringTask  {

    public void execute() {
        // enter code
    }
}
```

and Spring's bean configuration file (`scheduler.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="recurringTask" class="RecurringTask" />

    <bean id="recurringJob"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="recurringTask" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="recurringTaskTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="recurringJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */20 * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <!-- timer factory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="recurringTaskTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Application launcher:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("scheduler.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so you say it is easier if I use Spring, right?

Comment: Spring can help you to decouple your code from the Quartz API. Check this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/) for sample code.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try this code and I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: I was wondering if there is another solution, becasue I didn't use Spring from the beginning. :/

Comment: @Garry answer includes a solution without Spring.

Comment: What about the part "Use it with Spring"?

Comment: These are two separate approaches without and with Spring respectively.